# Customize Navigation Tabs in Android Action bar

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar

I have an Android app that Im making now using one of the default templates: I believe it was Fixed Tabs + Swipe.

A screenshot of the current navigation bar is below (I marked the navigation bars in red for this SO question):

[image]

My question is, is it possible to customize these navigation tabs?  I would like to increase their height and also add an icon ideally on top of the text.  Also, Id like to change the colors.

Something like below:

```
|           |          |            |
|  icon     |  icon    |   icon     |
|           |          |            |
|           |          |            |
|  HOME     |   NEW    |  FAVORITE  |
```

I can't find any clear documentation that states that this type of navigation tabbar can be customized.  Is this pretty much set as is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to add icons to Actionbar tabs

```
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = bar.newTab();

    tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.homeicon);

    tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.newicon);

    tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.favicon);
```

And use icons like below (text should be bottom of image)

[image]

Comment: it just put icon on left, he wants it on top!

Comment: @ArunCThomas: What about now? Sometimes we need to use our own ideas ;)

Comment: Yes, I havent had good results with .setIcon.  Ideally I would like to set PNG files for the tabs themselves if possible.  I have tried to use .setCustomView for the tab, but so far nothing shows up.

Comment: what is the problem using setIcon method?